# How do I write output to the console from a custom MSBuild task?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm trying to debug an MSBuild task, and I know there is some way to write to the MSBuild log from within a custom task but I forget how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx) class has a `Log` property you can use:

```
Log.LogMessage("My message");
```

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing purposes, I wrap the logger around a helper class

```
public static void Log(ITask task, string message, MessageImportance importance)
{
    try
    {
        BuildMessageEventArgs args = new BuildMessageEventArgs(message, string.Empty, 
            task.ToString(), importance);
        task.BuildEngine.LogMessageEvent(args);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        // Don't throw as task and BuildEngine will be null in unit test.
    }
}
```

Nowadays I'd probably convert that into an extension method for convenience.